# Find intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{4}}, i). $ Which of the extensions are normal over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, galois-extensions

Find intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{4}}, i). $ Which of the extensions are normal over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

I don't have any clue on how to procceed with this, I think I must find a polynomial for which  $\mathbb{Q}(2^{\frac{1}{4}}, i). $ results to be its splitting field, but then I don't know what to do or how to determine which extension is normal, so any hint would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The fundamental theorem of Galois theory is a good start.  There will be $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i): \mathbb{Q}]$ automorphisms in the Galois group of that field, and the correspondence tells us that this number is equal to the number of intermediate fields (including the base field and the whole thing).  So we just need to find $6$ more intermediate fields and we're done.  The correspondence further says that the normal extensions are those fixed by a normal subgroup of the Galois group.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$ is the splitting field of $x^4-2$.